# Script taking forever to generate unique ID

Tags: javascript, html, peerjs

My javascript script loads at random times and the unique id takes forever to appear on the website. Is there a way I could have the script load first thing before other features of my website loads? I have tried putting the script for this at the very top of the html, but it still takes a long time. **Show-peer** is what's taking forever to display

```
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
        <li class="logged-in" style="display: none;">
            <input id="peerID" placeholder="Peer ID" class="grey-text">
        </li>
        <li class="logged-in" style="display: none;">
            <a id="call-peer" class="grey-text">Call Peer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="logged-in" style="display: none;">
            <a id="screenShare" class="grey-text">Screen share</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="gray-text" id="show-peer"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        var peer = new Peer()
        var myStream;
        var currentPeer;
        var peerList = [];
        peer.on('open', function (id) {
            document.getElementById("show-peer").innerHTML = id
        })
        peer.on('call', function (call) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: true
            }).then((stream) => {
                myStream = stream
                addOurVideo(stream)
                call.answer(stream)
                call.on('stream', function (remoteStream) {
                    if (!peerList.includes(call.peer)) {
                        addRemoteVideo(remoteStream)
                        currentPeer = call.peerConnection
                        peerList.push(call.peer)
                    }

                })
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err + " unable to get media")
            })
        })
        function stopScreenShare() {
            let videoTrack = myStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            var sender = currentPeer.getSenders().find(function (s) {
                return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
            })
            sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack)
        };
        document.getElementById("call-peer").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            let remotePeerId = document.getElementById("peerID").value;
            document.getElementById("show-peer").innerHTML = "connecting " + remotePeerId;
            console.log(remotePeerId)
            callPeer(remotePeerId);
        })
        document.getElementById("screenShare").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                video: {
                    cursor: "always"
                },
                audio: {
                    autoGainControl: false,
                    echoCancellation: false,
                    googAutoGainControl: false,
                    noiseSuppression: false
                }
            }).then((stream) => {
                let videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];

                videoTrack.onended = function () {
                    stopScreenShare()
                }
                let sender = currentPeer.getSenders().find(function (s) {
                    return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind
                })
                sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack)
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log("unable to get display media" + err)
            })
        })
        function callPeer(id) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: true
            }).then((stream) => {
                myStream = stream
                addOurVideo(stream)
                let call = peer.call(id, stream)
                call.on('stream', function (remoteStream) {
                    if (!peerList.includes(call.peer)) {
                        addRemoteVideo(remoteStream)
                        currentPeer = call.peerConnection
                        peerList.push(call.peer)
                    }

                })
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err + " unable to get media")
            })
        }
        function addRemoteVideo(stream) {
            let video = document.createElement("video");
            video.classList.add("video")
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play()
            document.getElementById("remoteVideo").append(video)
        }
        function addOurVideo(stream) {
            let video = document.createElement("video");
            video.classList.add("video")
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play()
            video.muted = true;
            document.getElementById("ourVideo").append(video)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this PeerJS?

Comment: @myjobistobehappy Yes

Comment: Huh. It didn't show at all for me